# draw canvas in showCaseView

Tags: android, canvas, showcaseview

I am new in android programming. I have decided to add a tour in my app using ShowCaseView Library. I have seen samples and examples of using this in applications. And I have checked relative links and questions.

As far as concerned, with using ShowCaseView, I can set Title and Description to guide users.
But I couldn't realize how to draw canvas (for example draw a pointer) on screen with ShowCaseView .

Can anyone please help me to draw a custom canvas using showcaseview to guide users?

Thanks in advance